# How does one change the colour of the text within UIDatePicker?

Tags: swift, xcode, uidatepicker

I'm very new to Swift and XCode. I can't find an option in the attributes box to change the text colour of the UIDatePicker. I want it white so it shows up on dark background.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
 yourDatePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

it change your datePicker text color to white
if you want change to another color just replace your color with UIColor.white